# Unable to delete xml file from app/build folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I tried to add a background for a theme (ActionBar),
but then everything went wrong.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:background">"colorPrimary"</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.MinWidth" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DialogWhenLarge" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

and I got this message:

```
Error:(4, 41) String types not allowed (at 'android:background' with value '"colorPrimary"').
```

decided to revert my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.MinWidth" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DialogWhenLarge" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge"/>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

but then it showed the same error,and the XML file is not really edited.

tried some solutions such as:

1.clean project (didn't work)
2.re-build project (didn't work)
3.delete app/build folder and run AS again (didn't work)
4.run AS as administrator (didn't work)
5.close Android Studio and run again (didn't work)
6.delete only the res folder (didn't work)

everything went wrong.

directory: app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml

Any solutions?

Comment: use color file in place of colorPrimary string like

Comment: <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

Comment: Try this
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate & Restart

Comment: can't edit the file at all. even when i change to @color/colorPrimary it changes to the invalid code back again. btw Invalidate & Restart also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the `@color` to your background tag :

just change your

```
<item name="android:background">"colorPrimary"</item>
```

line with this

```
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

and it saying the truth what you have is just a string ,and android has no way to know you meant the colorPrimary value in color resources.

hope this help.